# Strong law of large numbers for Poisson rvs with different parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_n$ be independent Poisson random variables with $E[X_i] = \mu_i$, and let $Y_n = X_1+...+X_n$. I want to show that if $\sum_n \mu_n = \infty $ then $Y_n/E[Y_n] \rightarrow 1$ almost surly.
What I do know is that if $X_1,...$ are independent, and $E\left[X^4\right] < \infty$, then $Y_n/n \rightarrow E[X]$ a.s.* So What I tried is to center the random variables: let $C_n := X_n-\mu_n$. The $C$'s are independent, $E[C_n^4]< \infty, E[C_n] = 0$, which means:
$\frac{C_1 +...+C_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s., or $\frac{\sum X_i - \sum \mu_i}{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s. which, I think, completes the proof.

However I am not sure why the requirement $\sum_n \mu_n = \infty $ is necessary, so I suspect this proof is incorrect. Is it?

Edit:  This argument is incorrect since the theorem requires $E[C^4]$ to be uniformly bounded, not just bounded. Any ideas?

- [This is the statement of the theorem from "Probability with Martingales"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SscQX.png)

Comment: You cannot apply the result you recall since it requires the increments are identically distributed -- which is not true in your case (except if $\mu_n$ does not depend on $\mu$).

Comment: To see why the $\sum_n\mu_n=\infty$ requirement is needed consider what happens if $\mu_1=1$ and 
 $\mu_n=0$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @Did - The result I cited does not require i.d. See "Probability with martingales" Chapter 7

Comment: Except you misquoted heavily.

Comment: @kimchilover If $\mu_n = 0$ it would mean that $X_n = 0$, so I am not sure where is the problem

Comment: @Did - why? the important assumptions are: (1) $E(X)=0$, and (2) $E(X^4)$ finite. What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: That the statement "What I do know is that if $X_1,...$ are independent, and $E\left[X^4\right] < \infty$, then $Y_n/n \rightarrow E[X]$ a.s." is **obviously** wrong. But I thought you were saying this was verbatim from Williams' PWM? Not anymore?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the exact claim, not sure where the difference between what I cited and this. @Did

Comment: @Did based on the answer, what I misquote is that $E(X^4)$ should be uniformly bounded, not just bounded, which makes my argument false. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in your argument, $M=\sum_n \mu_n<\infty$ then your $Y_n$ converge in distribution to a Poisson rv. with expectation $M$, and your ratio $Y_n/EY_n$ has a non trivial limit distribution, violating a.s. convergence to a constant.

And, the theorem you quote  needs a uniform 4th moment bound $EX_k^4\le K$,  which need not hold given your hypotheses.

A better way to prove your result might be to write your $Y_n$ as $Y_n=Y(M_n)$, where $M_n=\sum_{t\le n} \mu_t$ and where $Y(t)$ is a Poisson process, as described in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Homogeneous_Poisson_point_process).  You might be able to show $Y(t)/t\to 1$ almost surely.

Alternatively, you could use your argument with the added hypothesis that $\mu_n\le1$ for all $n$ and then use that to prove the general result by representing each $\mu_n$ as a sum of quantities that are individually bounded by $1$, and your corresponding $Y_n$ as sums of independent Poissons whose expectations are bounded and add up to the right thing.

Comment: I see. So: the overall argument is correct, except the punch: $C_1+...+C_n /n \rightarrow 0$ implies the claim only if $M = \infty$, or should I change the entire argument? The comments in the original question made me completely not sure about is correctness. Thanks!

Comment: Re the edit: I see now that my argument is not true due to the uniform bounded requirement. Do you think that there is a proof which is not going through Poisson process?

Comment: I suppose there could be a non-Poisson process proof, but it would probably be ugly, like an apparatus designed by a lawyer to not infringe on a particular patent.

Comment: Thanks. May you elaborate more on this way of proof? I am not familiar with Poisson processes, so I read about it but still have no idea how to use it here